# ASP.NET Add and Show Controls Asynchron, not Synchron?

Tags: c#, asp.net, load

I have a Control: `Image`

And I'm adding the image in a `foreach`, in my `divContainer`.

The Problem is, that there are about **100 Images**. Now the website loads and at the end
when all Images were been loaded, **it shows me the result!**

But I want an **asynchron** view/result, so that I don't have to **wait**, till every image has been **loaded**, it should add the Images in front of my eyes - one after the other.

Thats the Code, which adds the Image to the Div: `myDiv.Controls.Add(image);`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET works by building up the HTML then outputting it to the browser, it won't send them one by one.

Does building the html to output really take up that much time anyway?

If its getting to the browser then the browser doesn't show all the images until each one is loaded then its the browser doing this. The browser can finish the layout of the page and start showing images if you make sure you have the height and width set on each image tag when it goes out.

Comment: I assumed that, but is there not a way, how it even would be possible to do? I don't think, that I'm the only one who had that problem..

Comment: The only way to do what I think you want is via Javascript. Have a look at this: http://csharptuning.blogspot.com/2007/05/loading-images-asynchronously-with.html. Is this what you are after?